# How do you pass the object selected in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath to new UIViewControllers pushed onto the stack?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm displaying a list of items in a tableViewController, then when a row is selected pushing a viewController with a .xib file onto the stack, giving a more detailed explanation of the item in a textView with a few UIButtons to select for further action.  All of this works so far.

The problem I'm running into is pushing yet another viewController onto the stack with editable textViews containing information from the original object selected in the tableView.  I can get the viewController and .xib to load, but not the data.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    JASDetailViewController *dvc = [[JASDetailViewController alloc]init];

    NSArray *ideas = [[JASIdeaStore sharedStore]allIdeas];

    JASIdea *selectedIdea = ideas[indexPath.row];

    dvc.idea = selectedIdea;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

This populates the DetailViewController perfectly.  Then, when moving to the next viewController:

```
- (IBAction)editButton:(id)sender
{

    JASEditViewController *evc = [[JASEditViewController alloc]init];

    //NSIndexPath *path = (NSIndexPath *)sender;

    //NSIndexPath *path = [[NSIndexPath alloc]init];

    //path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];

    NSArray *ideas = [[JASIdeaStore sharedStore]allIdeas];

    JASIdea *selectedIdea = // Looking for a solution here. . .


    evc.idea = selectedIdea;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:evc animated:YES];    
}
```

I can get the EditViewController to load, but not the data. The gaps and commented out sections represent some of my attempts to get this to work.  By specifying a particular indexPath, I can make an idea show up, but have been unable to get my original selection from the tableView to pass through.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, excellent answers.  Looks like I was complicating the simple by overlooking the ability to use self in this case.  Again, many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want this?

`JASIdea *selectedIdea = self.idea;`

If I understand your code correctly, you're going from an edit button on `JASDetailViewController` to `JASEditViewController`, but the `JASIdea` instance is staying the same.  You passed `selectedIdea` from your table view's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` into `JASDetailViewController.idea`.  That means that it's there in `self.idea` when you're inside `JASDetailViewController.editButton`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting your data from a shared instance, there's no need to pass selectedIdea to JASDetailViewController. Instead, you should create a property, lets call it selectedIndex, and pass that. That way, you'll have that value to pass on to JASEditViewController as well.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    JASDetailViewController *dvc = [[JASDetailViewController alloc]init];
    dvc.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

In viewDidLoad of JASDetailViewController, you can get the selected idea with,

```
JASIdea *selectedIdea = ideas[self.selectedIndex];
```